# jshint not recognizing devel

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm using jshint and have the following options defined:

```
/*global $, _*/
/*jshint devel:true*/
```

My understanding is that by having `/*jshint devel:true*/` it should allow console and alert, but I continue to get errors on them.  Any ideas if there's something else I need to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you running jshint? The website jshint.com or is it some plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a space between the e and *

```
/*jshint devel:true */
```